# why is data warehouse time dependent?

Tags: data-warehouse

In my textbook, it says that data in data warehouse is only valid for a period of time, in other words, it is considered to be time dependent but as per the four characteristics of data warehouse, non-volatile property says that once the data has been entered inside the data warehouse, it can't be changed at any cost.

So is there any other property of data warehouse which talks about data warehouse being time dependent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did your textbook say "time dependent", or "time variant"? It may be paraphrasing Bill Inmon's definition that a data warehouse is subject oriented, integrated, time variant, and non-volatile.

"Time variant" means that the data warehouse is entirely contained within a time period. Another way of stating that, is that the DW is consistent within a period, meaning that the data warehouse is loaded daily, hourly, or on some other periodic basis, and does not change within that period.

Keeping in mind that these requirements were written in 1992, they are a little difficult to support some 25 years later, when real-time data warehousing is a reality, and the data warehouse may change several times per second.

Also, be careful of the definition of "non-volatile." Some people interpret it to mean that the data can never change, but this is again an outdated concept. An accumulating snapshot fact table showing a forecast shipment date for an order may well be updated many times during the life of the order. Of course, that depends on the purpose of the fact - if it was to measure volatility in forecast dates we'd keep every change, but if it is to measure the flow of an order through its life cycle, we'd just update it.

Personally, I prefer Ralph Kimball's definition, "A data warehouse is a copy of transaction data specifically structured for query and analysis." Much more clear and to the point.